# Windows service sql server authenication issue

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssis

I have a windows service that is executing a SSIS package from C# which requires Windows authentication in able to work. I have the service log on account using a domain account with appropriate permissions and I get this error message:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

The service is actually running on the database server for performance reasons. Obviously this works on my development machine. It is a SQL Server 2012 server running on Windows 2008.

Comment: What does the connection string look like? Is the domain account a user in SQL with the proper permissions?

Comment: Here is the connection string: Data Source=fqdn;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=60. I tried my account as I can login with no issues. I also tried the domain administrator. My account has been granted sysadmin server role so I assume that should let me in.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the actual servername, not a dns entry. I ran select @@servername and used that name. We use sql authentication for all of our applications and use a fqdn but it seems that does not work with integrated authentication. I have not seen this documented anywhere.